# Login with python mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am trying to create a python script that uses mechanize to submit data to a web form.

This is what I have so far

```
import mechanize


username = <my_username>
password = <my_password>
url = <my_url>


print "opening browser"
br = mechanize.Browser()
print "opening url...please wait"
br.open(url)
print br.title()
print "selecting form"
br.select_form(name='Login')
br['UserID'] = username
br['PassPhrase'] = password
print "submitting form"
br.submit()
```

I'm stuck on what to do now. Does `br` now contain the next webpage than comes up after submitting the form? Is there a way I can print the `html` in `br` to check what webpage is in it? (I cant use `print br.title()` because both pages have the same title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this at the end:

```
response = br.submit()
pageSource=response.read()
```

pageSource should give you the html-source of the post-login page.

Comment: Ok, now i need to submit forms on the next page. can I just call `br.select_form` again or do I need to call `br.set_response(response)`?

Comment: I don't have mechanize on my current device, but try just using `select_form`. If memory serves me well, it should work